# Emberjs - modifying array

Tags: ember.js

I have some issue with Ember that I don't really understand. I have an array like this :

```
var device.images = [
    0: {
        url: "url",
        key: "key"
    },
    1: "url2",
    2: "url3",
    3: "url4"
];'
```

And in my controller, inside a map I try to modify every item from the array doing this :

`device.images[idx] = image;`

`image` is a new object that look like the first item of my array. But I always get the assertion failed :

`Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to access this property (of [object Object]...`

How can I fix that ? because that should normally works no ?

[edit] Here is the complete code :

```
loadGallery: function( device ) {

        var that = this;
        var images = device.images.map( function( item, idx ) {
            return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function( resolve ) {
                if ( item.url ) {
                    resolve( item );
                }
                else {
                    resolve( that.imageStore.readImage( that, item ) );
                }
            })
            .then( function( image ) {
                device.images.set( idx, image );
                that.set( 'selectedItem.images', device.images );
                return image;
            });
        });
        return Ember.RSVP.Promise.all( images );
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit: first attempt was wrong]

It seems you should be able to use `item[index] = value` construct. Example usage:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  resolveImage: function (that, item) {
    return {
      url: item,
      key: "resolved"
    };
  },
  model: function() {
    var device = {
      images: [
        {url: "a", key: "existing"},
        "b",
        "c"
      ]
    };
    var that = this;
    var images = device.images.map(function(item, idx) {
      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
        if (item.url) {
          resolve(item);
        }
        else {
          resolve(that.resolveImage(that, item));
        }
      })
      .then(function(image) {
        device.images[idx] = image;
        return image;
      });
    });
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      model: Ember.RSVP.Promise.all(images),
      device: device
    });
  },
  setupController: function (c, m) {
    c.set("model", m.model);
    c.set("device", m.device);
  }
});
```

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <h2>From model</h2>
  <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{item.url}} - {{item.key}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  <h2>From device</h2>
  <ul>
    {{#each item in device.images}}
      <li>{{item.url}} - {{item.key}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  </script>
```

[JSBin here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vusomuni/4/edit).

Barring some bug elsewhere in your code, the only remaining solution is that you are using `Ember.Data` and `images` isn't really an array but a custom class that merely implements one or several of Ember's array/enumerable mixins. `[...]` construct is a syntactic sugar that is hardcoded into javascript and not available to library authors to override.

I can't help you there much, as I don't use Ember.Data. You can try using explicit array mutation methods from [Ember.MutableArray](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html) interface. Eg:

```
device.images.replace(idx, 1, [image]);
```

Alternatively, use `object.set(key, value)` construct (my first suggestion), with caveat that key value must be a string. Eg:

```
device.images.set(String(idx), image);
```

If neither of these work, you can just try to build up a new array instead of replacing members of the existing one.

Comment: I tried this, but I got `Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot call set with 0 key.`. My idx here is the iteration from my map (I have edited the main post). That should works... :/ Also, device is just some data retrieve from a click event (like, which device the user clicked on).

Comment: Hmm, looked at it again, seems if you're using ordinary array, you should be able to use `array[x] = y` construct. [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vusomuni/3/edit). What exactly is `device.images` in your case?

Comment: I load a list of product in my model, each product has some informations and an array of images with url in it. When the use click  on a product, it will trigger my handler `{{action 'selectDevice' device}}` that will send the object of the device clicked. So, basically, device is an object, and device.images is an array in device object. And I just needed to replace each item of the array with an object.

Comment: Edited answer, under assumption you're using Ember.Data. Can't replicate your failure state in jsbin. If none of these two ideas work, try fiddling the JSBin test case into the same failure state you're getting.

Comment: Yes I'm using Ember-Data, `device.images.set( idx+'', image);` seems to work. But when I do `that.set( 'selectedItem.images', device.images );` why is selectedItem is not refresh into my template ? 
I have debugged `devices.images`, and it has the correct data in it now.

Comment: That part looks like an unrelated bug. You're calling this every time you process an image. Try `return Ember.RSVP.Promise.all(images).then(function (images) { /* set it here */ })`

Comment: Yeah, that was the main purpose of this map loop also, to display a new image when its done loading instead of doing `Ember.RSVP.Promise.all(images).then(function (images) { /* set it here */ })` and this will load them all at the end.. I know that's not the question here, but do you know why this doesn't work ?

Comment: Not enough information to guess. If you don't figure it out, best start another topic.